# Looking for RF electronics design references

Tags: rf, design, books

I’m looking for novice-level references for RF design - something targeting an enthusiastic hobbyist or engineer from a different discipline, but who isn’t a proper EE/doesn’t have specific background in the field. Think along the lines of Practical Electronics for Inventors, but focused on RF. Any suggestions appreciated!

(Background: I am messing around with UHF in a project, and would like to understand more specifically about how antennas and cables are designed)

Answer (score 7):

Get yourself a copy of the ARRL (American Radio Relay League) Handbook which is designed for radio amateurs so it is at a very understandable level for non-engineers. It is published every year but an older issue will do fine since the fundamentals of RF design do not change. Also older issues can be purchased for very reasonable prices.

Comment: A google search of "arrl handbook pdf" also returns some pdf download links. One can check it out. Not sure how legal it is though.

Answer (score 0):

I like this book:

From Resistor to Radio by Daniel Chermetz

[https://www.amazon.com/Resistor-Radio-Electronics-applications-circuit/dp/B0BCD8CTNR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BCD8CTNR)

I've built some of the radio circuits in this book:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xZX3g8I4X0

But the trouble is that the recipes in that book are maybe only 85-90% accurate. Whenever I've built circuits from that book, I've always had to add some resistor to avoid oscillation, change the degree of amplification (radio signal varies from area to area), or an extra capacitor to stabilise noise.

I'm not sure if a person without a good deal of pre-existing experience would be able to know those troubleshooting tricks (unlike other circuits, radios have lots of unknowns and usually require a bit of tweaking - the smallest thing can make it go from loud parasitic oscillation noise to nearly perfect radio).

But at least, the circuit can be simulated on the Falstad circuit simulator or on LTSpice. (Even then some care is needed to set the right timestep size, and the right input signal voltages - so the input signal would be within the acceptable range).

But for a UHF book (I myself stop at VHF in my FM radio design, so UHF is quite ambitious, at least for me), I personally don't think there's a substitute for "real" academic books. One I like is **Microwave Transistor Amplifiers by Gonzalez**. But please note, that it's better to approach it only after already being pretty good with transistor design on an audio to Medium radio frequency level. Otherwise, it might prove a bit of a misdirection (the way I view it).

I personally also like the topic of radios and transistor design, so I naturally wish good luck to anyone else who's interested (not very many it seems as far as AM and FM radios are concerned).